# What's the correct way to init yii2 framework with push-to-deploy

Tags: php, git, yii, yii2

I've created `post-receive` hook for git repository which checkouts commit to web folder `/var/www/myproject`. Since I'm not committing dependencies (framework files), when checked out I have to install dependencies and init the framework. I see two approaches:

1) When checked out run the following commands from the project directory:

```
composer install
php init --env=Development --overwrite=n
#other commands to setup db connection, credentials etc.
```

2) Install dependencies one level up of checked out project `/var/www` and have links one level up. But it seems that with this approach I'll still need to run `php init`.

What's the common approach for such deployment?

Comment: Are you using the `advanced` app template? If you are, it's surprising you're checking your project out to `/var/www/`. If you are not (if you're using `basic` app), you don't need `init`.

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure which template I'm using, but I'm doing `init`. Why is it surprising to check out to `/var/www`?

Comment: Only advanced app has `init` script, which is used to set up config files from a certain set defined in `environments` dir. Actually, you're right, it's fine as long as you have `/var/www/myproject/frontend/web` and `/var/www/myproject/backend/web` set as web root.

Comment: yeah, so how do you push-deploy andvance app?

Answer (score 0):

An important feature of the advanced app is having separate backend and frontend apps. So if you check out your repo to `/var/www/myproject`, two important directories will be created: `/var/www/myproject/frontend/web` and `/var/www/myproject/backend/web`. You usually configure your web server to have these two directories as web roots for two different domains (like `example.com` and `admin.example.com`).

Yii2 advanced app introduces the concept of "environments". An environment is basically a set of config files, that, among other things, include db credentials. So if you don't mind having credentials in your repo, push-deployment is possible.

So if you plan to have multiple servers with multiple configs, you just create an environment for each server and use it to deploy.

So here are the steps you need to take after checking out the repo.

1. Install composer dependencies: `composer install`

Pretty straightforward. Keep in mind that `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` needs to be installed globally for composer to fetch bower and npm dependencies.

2. Check out a certain environment for current setup: `init --env=your_server_environment --overwrite=All`

You should overwrite everything. If you have updated some parameter in your environment, it will be applied to the current setup.

3. Migrate the database: `yii migrate --interactive=0`

That's all there is to it.